# How to run .exe file within program

Tags: java

In eclipse, if you have a .exe file in the package how would you run it? I know if it is outside you would just add in the path, but what would the path be for something inside the project?

Comment: Qualify it with path same as if it was outside. Or are you asking how to code the Java program to pick up the Eclipse project home directory? If so, the code won't be able to run outside of Eclipse, and that's hardly useful.

Comment: no I'm just trying to run a program that would be embedded within the jar file when it is exported.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets imagine a File f = new File(Path);

If in that case we have the file inside our project (same directory),then we dont need to add the path, just the file name and extension (ex: .txt)......I guess in your case it would be something similar.

Comment: Well I already have a file in the same package, and Runtime to execute isn't working.